# Autocomplete field consisting of multiple fields

Tags: ajax

I am trying something that have been probably discussed already, but I can't seem to find it.  I have a node reference field that I would like to use the "Autocomplete field" function with. However, I would like to show an extra (custom) field, not only the Title of the node. Preferably in a comma separated list, like:

TITLE Node 1, custom field
TITLE Node 2, custom field

etc.

I'm sure this can be done. But I can't seem to find how (and yes.. I'm a beginner I'm affraid).

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using Node Reference ([References](https://drupal.org/project/references)), I suggest you to use [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module. It has an option to build the autocomplete options with a view so that you can add other fields.

Comment: Clean way,I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using references module for node reference.

You can get better hold of how you can do this looking inside sub-module of references module called "node-references".

you need to check if this idea works for you.

1. Implement [hook_field_widget_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7) in your custom module,implementing this hook you can change the callback function which provides autocomplete suggestions.

As in node_refernce.module line number 606 node_reference_field_widget_form() has been implemented so keeping the same workflow you just have to override `"value_callback"` with your custom function.Lets call you custom as "`custom_autocomplete_suggestions()`"

1. Now in your custom function `custom_autocomplete_suggestions()` copy the code of existing callback function in node_references module.
2. Clear your caches, check if you getting autocomplete suggestions or not.If so you have overridden it successfully.
3. Now do tweaks inside your `custom_autocomplete_suggestions()` to return what you want as suggestions.